# Selenium TestNG dependency clarification design

Tags: java, selenium, testng

as I am experimenting with TestNG using a UDEMY course, I need clarification on dependency part. Below I have a method  that will log into gmail
called gmailLogin(). I have a separate method that searches for a topic in the Gmail search box(once you have logged in), called gmailSearch().

You need to be logged into your Gmail account to perform the search. I did 2 things to experiment

1) Gave incorrect information in gmailLogin(). This will fail.
2) I did not use dependsOnMethods="gmailLogin" in  gmailSearch().

Test gmailSearch() does not fail because  it uses google home page search  from @BeforeMethod. Google home page's search also uses  name='q'.

Question: What would be a good way to design the gmailSearch() method so that it is forced to use gmailLogin()? If the current process is a bad design then should I combine
login and search in 1 method?

Thank in advance for taking the time to explain/answer.

```
public class GoogleTest {

    static WebDriver driver;    

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void googleSearch(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).sendKeys("news");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']")).click();
        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("www.foxnews.com")){
            System.out.print("Search found");
        }       
    }
    @Test(priority=2,groups="Gmail")
    public void gmailIcon(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm']")).click();
        if(driver.getTitle().contains("Gmail")){
            System.out.print("Gmail found");
        }       
    }
    @Test(priority=2,groups="Gmail")
    public void gmailLogin(){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("aname@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("psd123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
        if(driver.getTitle().contains("Inbox")){
            System.out.print("Gmail Inbox");
        }       
    }
    @Test(groups="Gmail")
    public void gmailSearch(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).sendKeys("QA"+ "\n");
        if(driver.getTitle().contains("Search Results")){
            System.out.print("Gmail Search");
        }       
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void testDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have everything in only one class which is not a good idea, you need to have separate classes for each page.
It is better to use POM (Page Object Model). In your case, you have two different pages, login page and Gmail page. So you need a class for each one. Then you can have classes for your test case. For example, login and search, in this class you can call login and search.
You also need to verify login and then start searching (you can have a test to check the username to make sure user is logged in and then if that was ok you can perform the test).
Using POM will help you manage your tests better especially if your test project will be large.
You can read more about POM [here](https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html).

Comment: Thanks Hamid, I will try this with POM concept as well. I was trying to see using the TestNG dependency if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you should use `dependsOnMethods` to create a method dependency. That is methodB should be executed only after methodA, then methodB should have dependsOnMethods="methodA"

`@Test(dependsOnMethods="methodA")`

---

If you are new to Selenium automation, your test looks ok. But it can be improved much better. You are trying to handle everything in a single class.

This class does the following

- running the tests
- managing the lifecycle of webdriver instance
- application business logic
- test data management

Ideally each class should have only one responsibility. I would advise you to take a look at below sites for better design

- [Designing proper TestNG tests](http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-design-tests-test-data/)
- [Advanced Page Objects Design](http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/)